# serenity-js- How to use before and after hooks

Tags: cucumberjs, serenity-js

How to use before and after hooks in serenity-js, without using Mocha? Any sample code available in the cook book?

Answer (score 0):

Handling before and after hooks is the responsibility of a test runner, rather than Serenity/JS itself.

You can find out more in the documentation of both of the supported test runners:

- Cucumber - https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/1.x/docs/support_files/hooks.md
- Mocha - https://mochajs.org/#hooks

Hope this helps!
Jan